# Transforming raster with matrix

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterio, affine-transformation, rotate

I would like to apply a similarity transformation matrix (potentially a homography matrix) on a valid raster (with proper CRS, resolution, bounds, width height, etc).

The 1st image is the original image. The 2nd image is the bounds being rotated 30 degrees but the pixels are not.

How do I apply a transformation matrix on a raster in a way that the transformation matrix can be multiplied with a raster's affine transform?

[image: 2nd image][image]